# how to select an element using jquery cycle

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

thumbnails.html: This page contains 16 images. The user then select an image and a new page "display.htm" is loaded. On this page i am using jquery cycle and the images slowly rotate.

My question is, what jquery / cycle syntax can i use so that the "cycle" starts from the correct element. So let say the user clicks on the fourth image i need a way to ensure cycle starts at the fourth image. In my example i#m using 2 pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need it to start on the 4th element, just specify that when you initialize the plugin...

```
$('#gallery').cycle({ 
    startingSlide: 3
});
```